# Do notify/verify work without submit button?

Tags: javascript, validation, notify, verify

I have a very simple form:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <input id="in1" type="text" data-validate="required">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input id="in2" type="text" data-validate="required">
    </fieldset>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Insert your datas" onclick="insert()">
</form>
```

If third input (`id:"btn"`) had `type="submit"`, notify/verify would work well.

I don't need to submit this form (because I have to launch an `insert()` function on button `onclick`),

so I **deleted** the **submit type** of my button and unfortunately no notifications appear on my page now.

I may add an handler (like this: `$(".elem-demo").notify("Hello Box")`) as notify docs suggest, but that is a custom notification, good, but I want to take advantage of `verify.js` `data-validate`..no extra-code required for a simple validation like **"required"** or **"number"**.

How can I fix that?
I wish I was clear of my issue and thanks to answer me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the button type submit and can override the default form submission behavior on submit button click via `event.preventDefault()`

```
<form id="my-form" onSubmit="myFunction(event)">
    <fieldset>
        <input id="in1" type="text" data-validate="required">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input id="in2" type="text" data-validate="required">
    </fieldset>
    <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Insert your datas" onclick="insert()">
</form>
```

This your function which will be called on form submission.Access the form via its id and call `validate` to check form for errors.
Calling `validate` will trigger validation on every element in the form. It accepts a callback function `callback(success)` which will be called after validation.

```
function myFunction(e){
 e.preventDefault();

 $("#my-form").validate(callbackFunction);

 // call your other function

}
```

Comment: thanks @WitVault, form submitting is overrided but I still haven't notifications by verify.js. As I already asked days ago, form is loaded by an ajax call and sent to my page. Can verify go wrong with ajax?

Comment: YES...it works finally adding $('#myformId').verify() in the callback function because verify method need to be required when dynamically adding new forms to the page..